# Why does TypeScript type conditional affect result of its branch?

Tags: typescript

I'm making a conditional type using the `?`operator in TypeScript. Based on a condition I want the type to be two different types. When doing this, I found, that the condition affects the branches.

The MRE is here:

```js
type Type1<O> = O extends never ? unknown : (undefined extends O ? 1 : 2);
type a = Type1<string | undefined>

type Type2<O> = undefined extends O ? 1 : 2;
type b = Type2<string | undefined>
```

or in [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEYA8B5AfFAvFFUIA9gIA7AEwGcpiIA3CAJygH4oBXYga2IHsB3YqAC4oACnakIAMwCW1UnkIkKOZlARCoAJgCUAbgBQoSFACGWWPGTlg9WQHMoAHzZkpsiKTT7D8C5E2oGNjibnIKRGSUuCzqwpoGRtAARuZw-kjWtsQOziEycl5AA).

I would expect `a` and `b` to be the same, as the condition `O extends never` should never be true, unless `O` is `never`. This is however not the case as `type a = 1 | 2` and `type b = 1`;

I cannot think of a reason, why the type union would be present, unless the condition in `Type1` somehow iterates over the `string | undefined` uninon.

Why is this the case? How can I work around this, if I want `a` to be only `1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are being surprised by [distribution over union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). Because you are using a naked type in left-hand side position in a conditional type, what you wrote is basically equivalent to writing `Type1<string> | Type1<undefined>`. All you need to do is wrap the operands in square brackets.

Comment: Yes it's one of those things... the feature can be useful, but why they didn't add syntax for this use case is beyond me. Unexpected behaviour and huge slow-downs inducing unions are common in TS. Don't hesitate to slap square brackets on conditionals